# Can not fetch html value attribute containing double quote

Tags: javascript, html

My html attribute is like below:

```
<span>
  <input 
    class="editWidgetName" 
    type="text" 
    maxlength="100" 
    value="Untitled "NAME" 30\10\2017" 
    style="display:none;padding-right:1px;"
    />
</span>
```

I can't fetch the value of the above 'editWidgetName' class. It's always fetching 'Untitled ' only. The string after '"' portion is getting omitted.
I tried javascript to escape the '"' like:
`value.replace(/\"/g, '\\"')` , but the result is same.

Again, I tried with encoding the value attribute using js function like:

```
function encodeHTML(s) {
    return s.split('&').join('&amp;')
            .split('<').join('&lt;')
            .split('"').join('&quot;')
            .split("'").join('&#39;');
}
```

but result is fetching as 'Undefined'.

Please suggest another way to resolve this.
Thanks.

Comment: can you create a snippet using `<>` showing how you are using this method `encodeHTML`?

Comment: How are you setting `s` (in your function `encodeHTML()`) ?

Comment: `value="Untitled "NAME" 30\10\2017"` is maybe the problem. You have to escape the inner double quotes.

Comment: I used like:

*var name = 'Untitled "NAME" 30\10\2017';*

*<span><input class="editWidgetName" type="text" maxlength="100" value="' + encodeHTML($.trim(name)) + '" style="display:none;padding-right:1px;"/></span>*

Yes, I also tried escaping the inner double quote like:
*name.replace(/\"/g, '\\"')*, but result is same.

Comment: @Quentin , this question is different than the marked question one, because as I already mentioned in my question that I've used those solution but that didn't work in my scenario. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @ProsenjitDutta — They should work. It sounds like your attempt to implement them was wrong. Try providing a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solve a problem means nothing. Take good habits is the solution.*

@ProsenjitDutta, make your best to separate the logic, the style and the container. As a start, you could:

- Never use the `style` attribute. Use CSS instead, with CLASSes and IDs attributes.
- Never write the value in the HTML code. Use Javascript instead (or templates).
- Take a time to find the best method (SO is your friend). To repeat split/join is a bad practice (slow and ugly), use Regexp instead.

```js
// Maybe typo here (fixed)----v   (backslash)

let name = 'Untitled "NAME" 30/10/2017'; 

// With jQuery:

$('#editWidget').val(name) ;

// Without jQuery

document.querySelector('#editWidget').value = name ;
```

```css
/**
  * Don't hard code the style in the tag
  * Use CSS instead (as below)
  *
  */
input.editWidgetName {
  width: 200px;
  padding-right: 1px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
<!--          v---------- an ID here                 -->
  <input id="editWidget" value="" class="editWidgetName" type="text" maxlength="100" />
<!--    empty value --------^                        -->

</span>
```

```js
function encodeHTML(s) {
  return s.replace(/([&<"'])/g, function(match, char){
  switch(char){
    case '&': return '&amp;';
    case '<': return '&lt;';
    case '"': return '&quot;';
    case "'": return '&#39;';
  }
})}

let s = "var=val<pour\"voir'ca'" ;

console.log('s = ', encodeHTML(s));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important;top:0;}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestion. I will definitely follow as you have suggested. Thanks once again.

Comment: Yes @Philicare I already tried to upvote as good answer, but as I've newly created this account, my current reputation is below 15. Hence my vote is not showing publicly.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're right! Thanks!;-) Don't forget to remove the unecessary comments under the answers/question (SO don't like the "thanks" ;-))

Comment: @Philicare, can you please upvote my question so that I can avoid blocking my account? Thanks a lot in advance.